# Uncaught ReferenceError: knockout is not defined - typescript, knockout and webpack issue

Tags: typescript, webpack, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement Knockout using Typescript and webpack but can't find it to work. I've installed npm "@types/knockout": "^3.4.66" and  "@types/knockout.validation": "0.0.37".

SignerViewModel.ts

```
import * as ko from "knockout";

export class SignerViewModel {
    public addressInfo: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public choosen: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    public companyName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    ...
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './Scripts/Ts-build/App',
    mode: 'development',
    target: 'web',
    watch: true,

    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js)?$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/Ts-build/'),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "source-map-loader"
        }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]
    },

    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery",
        "knockout": "knockout"
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            knockout: 'knockout'
        })
    ]
};
```

When I compile it with webpack I get no error. But when I run it I get the following error in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: knockout is not defined
    at Object.knockout (external "knockout":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../Scripts/Ts-build/ViewModels/SignerViewModel.js (SignerViewModel.ts:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../Scripts/Ts-build/App.js (App.ts:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        knockout: 'knockout'
    })
```

to this :

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        ko: 'exports-loader?!knockout'

    })
```

And make sure you have "exports-loader" package !

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the answer. I installed exports-loader and changed to that line in webpack.config, but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing "npm i knockout --save" and "npm i knockout.validation --save" and then removing the knockout from the webpack.config

SignerViewModel.ts

```
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as ko from "knockout";
import * as validation from "knockout.validation";

export class SignerViewModel {
    public addressInfo: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public choosen: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    public companyName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    ...
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    validation.registerExtenders();
    validation.init({ decorateInputElement: true, errorElementClass: "error" });
    ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(new SignerViewModel());
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './Scripts/Ts-build/App',
    mode: 'development',
    target: 'web',
    watch: true,

    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js)?$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/Ts-build/'),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "source-map-loader"
        }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]
    },

    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "knockout": "^3.4.2",
    "knockout-mapping": "^2.6.0",
    "knockout.validation": "^2.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/knockout": "^3.4.66",
    "@types/knockout.validation": "0.0.37",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.9",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```